# Swift - How to conform this struct to Codable?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, codable

I have this struct

```
struct Photo: Codable {
    var image: UIImage
    let caption: String?
    let location: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
}

private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case image = "image"
    case caption = "caption"
    case location = "location"
}
```

I get this 2 errors:

> Type 'Photo' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'
>
> Type 'Photo' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'

Comment: `UIImage` would have be `Codable`, and it is not. `CLLocationCoordinate2D` would have to be `Codable` too. Also `CodingKeys` would have to be an inner member of `Photo`. In this case they would not be needed at all. Your best bet is a custom encoding/decoding for `UIImage` by conversion to `Data` (png/jpeg) and probably to `String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Photo' does not conform to protocol Encodable/Decodable because UIImage cannot be conformed to Codable. Also `CLLocationCoordinate2D` cannot be conformed to Codable.
You can specify `var image` with `Data` type and then get UIImage from `Data`.

Something like this:

```
struct Photo: Codable {
    var imageData: Data
    let caption: String?
    let location: String?

    func getImage(from data: Data) -> UIImage? {
        return UIImage(data: data)
    }
}

private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case imageData = "image"
    case caption = "caption"
    case location = "location"
}
```

Comment: Note that sending the image data as JSON string would be really slow and it would also have its size considerably increased. I would just encode the image URL. Regarding location it would be much better to create a Location structure. `struct Location: Codable {
    let latitude, longitude: Double
}`

Comment: `enum CodingKeys` should be inside of `struct Photo`